# Can I automatically transfer Ether to a Bankaccount?

Tags: ether

I'm interested if it's possible to transfer Ether automatically (with conversion to a fiat currency) to a bankaccount without user interaction. For example with a SEPA transfer.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean by automatically. Some exchanges have APIs for the automatization of putting ETH up for sale, but even then you would have to transfer the funds to your account by hand, if you don't happen to be familiar with browser automation techniques by chance.